# xamarin crossmedia Camara is not working in vivo 1904

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, camera

I am using xamarin forms to create to create app.
I have implemented capturing picture from camera which is working fine for all other devices but it is not working in VIVO 1904

Permission for camera, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is added

below is the code:

> 

```
    public async void Capture()
    {
        try

        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

            if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Camera, Permission.Storage });
                cameraStatus = results[Permission.Camera];
                storageStatus = results[Permission.Storage];
            }


            var D = await DisplayActionSheet("Select action", "Cancel", null, new string[] { "Gallery", "Camera" });

            if (D == "Camera")
            {
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No camera available.", "OK");
                    return;
                }
                var requestedPermissions = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
                var requestedPermissionStatus = requestedPermissions[Permission.Camera];
                if (requestedPermissionStatus == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "Sample",
                        Name = "Attach.jpg",
                        PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                        AllowCropping = true
                    });
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    pathList.Add(new Path() { path = file.Path });
                    attachednolbl.Text = pathList.Count.ToString();
                }


                #region xamarin essential
                //var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                //if (photo == null)
                //{
                //    return;
                //}
                //// save the file into local storage
                //var newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
                //if (newFile == null)
                //{
                //    return;
                //}

                //using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                //{
                //    using (var newStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                //        await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
                //    long imageLength = stream.Length;
                //    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageLength];
                //    await stream.ReadAsync(imageBytes, 0, (int)imageLength);

                //    var pathStream = imageBytes;
                //    pathList.Add(new Path() { path = newFile });
                //    attachednolbl.Text = pathList.Count.ToString();
                //}
                #endregion



            }
            if (D == "Gallery")
            {
                string _imageSelected = string.Empty;
                if (Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Platform == Xamarin.Essentials.DevicePlatform.Android)
                {

                    await DependencyService.Get<IMediaService>().OpenGallery();


                    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected", async (s, images) =>
                    {

                        var ClickedOrSelectedImages = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
                        var selectedImages = new ObservableCollection<SelectedImages>();

                        // int i = 0;
                        foreach (var item in images)
                        {

                            pathList.Add(new Path() { path = item });

                        }
                        attachednolbl.Text = pathList.Count.ToString();
                        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelected");
                    });

                }
                else
                {

                    var media = CrossMedia.Current;
                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotosAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                    {
                        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,

                    });
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var item in file)
                        {
                            pathList.Add(new Path() { path = item.Path });
                        }
                        attachednolbl.Text = pathList.Count.ToString();
                    }



                }


                #region xamarin essential
                //var result = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(PickOptions.Images);
                //foreach (var photo in result)
                //{
                //    if (photo == null)
                //    {
                //        return;
                //    }
                //    // save the file into local storage
                //    var newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
                //    using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                //    {
                //        long imageLength = stream.Length;
                //        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageLength];
                //        await stream.ReadAsync(imageBytes, 0, (int)imageLength);
                //        var pathStream = imageBytes;
                //        // var image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(pathStream);
                //        pathList.Add(new Path() { path = photo.FullPath });
                //    }
                //}

                //attachednolbl.Text = pathList.Count.ToString();
                #endregion
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Please provide answer for it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide stack trace for your issue, as much as i might like i don't know what the issue is unless i have some debug log or something

Comment: I dont have this mobile. this was some else mobile who is far away. any ways issue solved. when android version is increase we have to add some storage permission